# How can I hide my top menu bar on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, menu-bar

I need to temporarily (5 min) hide my top menu bar. Is there a glitch, or something that will let me do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do it? I am honestly curious.

Comment: @John Smith : A certain app that i have, has a button just a little bit too low for my mouse to reach. If I could hide the menu bar I could access the button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few choices.

- [MenuFela](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=Menufela), site down, claims to do this.
- [MegaZoomer](http://www.ianhenderson.org/megazoomer.html) claims to zoom an app and hide the menu bar. Not sure if this will work, for example, with the Finder.
- [MenuShade](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070118003804854) does a so-so job. Hidden menu, but the shadow is there and the space is not usable
- According to [this hint](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070118003804854) you can edit the plist of the app and have the menu bar become hidden. Add the following to the Info.plist in the app bundle:

> ```
> <key>LSUIPresentationMode</key>
> <integer>4</integer>
> ```