# Hide/Show menu bar similar to dock?

Tags: macos

Do you know if it is possible to hide/show the menu bar similar to the Dock?
I found about [Menu Eclipse](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/menu-eclipse-2/id420041409?mt=12) , but I think you can't use the menu bar space, and additionally it costs $1.99. Do you know other alternatives?

Comment: Related questions: [5064](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5064/how-can-i-hide-my-top-menu-bar-on-mac-os-x), [53724](http://superuser.com/questions/53724/auto-hide-os-x-menu-bar), [68759](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68759/hide-application-menu-bar)

Answer (score 0):

As of OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), this functionality is built in to the operating system. Go to System Preferences > General  and turn on "Automatically hide and show the menu bar."

[image]